Accessing Mathematica from Python
I am trying to use some of the tools available in Mathematica within a Python program (or jupyter notebook) that I am writing.
I have already done:
pip install wolframclient

on my computer and this installation seemed to work fine.
But now I cannot find resources that tell me how to import these tools into my program or notebook.
I have tried:
import from WolframClientLibrary import WolframClient

I also tried this without any capital letters. This generates an error in python stating that it doesn't understand what the WolframClientLibrary is.
I suspect this is a really simple fix as I see others in StackOverflow using mathematica in their python programmes, so if someone would just give me the incantation I'd appreciate it.

you have a very nice documentation on their website on how to use the library https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/

This gets me started! Thanks.
